# SignalR in a complex n-tier application

Tags: asp.net, signalr

I have an n-tier legacy application that manages incident records and looks something like this:

[image]

Alerts are collated into Incident records by a Windows service and are reconciled to service desk tickets by users via the web application.

The web application has a listing page that currently reloads itself every minute.  I want to replace this polling behaviour by broadcasting any record changes using SignalR.

If this application was just the web part, the placement of SignalR hubs in the web tier would be simple.  My difficulty lies in how the Windows service notifies the hub it has made changes to the incident records.

As the web application is load balanced, I am thinking of using the [Sql instance to host a SignalR backplane](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/performance-and-scaling/scaleout-with-sql-server).  Could the windows service interact directly with this at all?

Am I going to have to create a third application to host the SignalR hub in and somehow have the web application and the Windows service communicate with that?

Any suggestions are most welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can host the `SignalR` within the ASP.net, it does not matter much. Your windows service should establish a connection and call some method on the `SignalR` whenever there are some changes made, so that the `SignalR` can then call the other clients about the changes.

Comment: This is what I was hoping to do.  I don't suppose you've seen an example of a windows service calling a web hosted hub anywhere?  I guess the trickiest part is the windows service is running on the sql box.

Comment: Honestly I haven't tried, but wouldn't it be just creating a connection with the right url and calling some method on it, as long as you have the right references and .net version.

Comment: Ok, so my windows service would have to act as a client and make http calls to the SignalR hub.  I found this - http://sonyarouje.com/2012/10/02/signalr-real-time-pushing-of-data-to-connected-clients/ - which is a similar use case.

Comment: Yes pretty much. This is the official MSDN link for Hub API and .NET client: http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/hubs-api/hubs-api-guide-net-client

Answer (score 0):

Unless I misunderstand something about your scenario, you can simply self-host the SignalR server in your windows service and create your hub classes there. You don't need to involve the web application in the SignalR communication at all, you simply use it to serve your static scripts. Your web page makes the SignalR connection to the server hosted in the Windows service and from there you can notify it of updates.